# I thought blah blah blah, and I was right. Is the comma correct?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

This sentence is bugging me:

> I knew going in that the orange flavor component of the cake was going to be lacking, and I was right.

The comma doesn't seem to be enough, but the semicolon just looks wrong:

> I knew going in that the orange flavor component of the cake was going to be lacking; and I was right.

Which of the above is correct and why?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The comma is enough as the second clause *"I was right"*  is **independent**.

Commas are used before conjunctions (*but, and, yet, or, so, etc.*) when the two clauses they are coordinating can stand as independent sentences.

The semicolon is used when the first clause contains commas.

> I knew going in that the orange, marzipan and chilli flavor component of the cake was going to be lacking; and I was right!

Comment: Agreed: I would say that in OPs example using both a semicolon and 'and' is actually misuse, but it's a very minor point. (Either would be better than both).

Comment: The semicolon is used a comma would be confusing.  My siblings were  born in Atlanta, Georgia; Oak Ridge, Tennessee and Los Angeles, California.  It serves as a kind of super-comma.  More importantly, it is used to joint two independent clauses where there is no conjunction.  You could say, "I knew going in that the orange flavor component of the cake was going to be lacking; I was right."  I'd agree that this particular use of the semicolon is "pretentious."  The semicolon is a wonderful punctuation mark; however, it is a mark that ought to be used judiciously.

Comment: I will always remember: `so, and, but, or, yet, for, nor`

Comment: Interestingly, in Italian you are usually taught not to use the comma at all in a case like this, precisely because you are using a conjunction that coordinates two independent sentences. The rationale is that you are just trying to reproduce the pause you make when you speak the sentence, so in other words it would be appropriate when writing direct speech, but not in a more formal setting.

Answer (score 15):

They are both right. As is

> I knew going in that the orange flavor component of the cake was going to be lacking.  And I was right.

Your examples are both *compound sentences*. There are two independent clauses, joined by a conjunction (*and*) and separated by punctuation (either the comma or the semicolon). The comma is a softer break, the semicolon, a more significant one.

My example uses two separate sentences. This is an even more significant break and is somewhat more dramatic. A few purist would argue that sentences should not begin with a conjunction, but that viewpoint is probably not very ascendant today. Or do you disagree?

[Perhaps I should have begun this entire discussion with *They are both right, as is ...*? Or maybe *They are both right; as is ...*?]

Comment: Ha! You bring up a good point regarding starting a sentence with a conjunction, it's kind of like ending a sentence with a preposition. "This is the sort of English up with which I will not put."

Comment: This usage of 'And' isn't a conjunction. A conjunction is something that joins two clauses, while this is an 'And' at the beginning of the sentence. Now let the purists rave.

Answer (score 9):

A comma seems fine.  A quick look at google books shows that commas are common here, though sometimes there’s no punctuation at all.

[image]

I found one case of parentheses, but not a single semicolon.

*The Economist*’s advice on semicolons is to use them:

> to mark a pause longer than a comma and shorter than a full stop. Don't overdo them.

So, it’s seems that a comma is fine in your example.

Comment: I particularly like the "don't overdo them". There is something oddly pretentious about the semicolon.

Comment: I think your first example has a syntax error rather than a stylistic preference.

Comment: @JFA: Do you want to add some more detail: what's the nature of the syntactic error?

Comment: @DanielHarbour Independent clauses need to be separated by commas. "I just knew it." and "I was right." can stand independently.

Comment: @Jeremy. That's a convention you can choose to follow if you like.  I note that several writers who I regard as great stylists (e.g., Atwood) do so only sometimes.  But I would certainly regard this comma rule as a matter of style, not one of syntax.  As a jobbing linguist, I regard syntax as being about why you have to say _John often eats fish_ rather that _John eats often fish_.  Maybe you place the division between grammar and style elsewhere.

Comment: @DanielHarbour Jeremy summed up what I was trying to say. As to whether its a stylistic preference vs an actual mistake is beyond what I know. I was taught there were very strict rules for punctuation, but it seems like as long as the meaning of the sentence is conveyed, punctuation rules can stay or leave.

Comment: @JFA: I'd hesitate to say that "rules of punctuation" have the same status as rules of grammar.  Pick up different style manuals and they'll advise differently on how to use semicolons, colons, em-dashes, en-dashes, and so on.  But none will tell you that "Loves Mary John" is an acceptable sentence of English.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct, and here is why.

You have two independent clauses in that sentence, and that means they must be: A) separated with a period. This is because they can stand alone as two separate sentences, 2) joined with a semicolon; do not use a conjunction, 3) joined with a comma and a conjunction, and they can be written as one sentence.

Which of these you choose depends on the style of your writing.